# Issue while using `boundingRectWithSize` for aligning UILabels in dynamic frames

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, nsstring, uilabel

I have two `UILabels` L1 and L2.

- The maximum width of L1 is 150
- Minimum width of L1 will be adjusted according to the text length
- The distance between the two labels is 10.

My code,

```
NSString *s = @"Stringwithoutspacetext";
L1.text = s;
L2.text = @"2";


CGSize  textSize = { 150, 21 };
CGRect textRect = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",s]
        boundingRectWithSize:textSize
        options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
        attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17]}
        context:nil];

L1.frame = CGRectMake(L1.frame.origin.x, L1.frame.origin.y, textRect.size.width, L1.frame.size.height);
L2.frame = CGRectMake(L1.frame.origin.x+textRect.size.width+10, L2.frame.origin.y, L2.frame.size.width, L2.frame.size.height);
```

It works fine when the string `s` has no space in it.

[image]

If the string has one space, ie. `s = @"String withspacetext";`

output looks like below,

[image]

If the string has two spaces, ie. `s = @"String with spacetext";`

output looks like below,

[image]

**Why the space text affects my code? What should I change in my code to work fine with the above conditions?**

Comment: Hmm... `L1.text = s;` and `L1.text = @"2"`? I didn't get that.

Comment: @Neeku, `s` is the NSString.

Comment: Yeah, I mean why are you assigning `@"2"` after `s`? wouldn't it replace it rather than merging? /me is confused!

Comment: @Neeku, edited, it's `L2.text`. Thnx

Comment: Ah. Ok. Edit helped. That's `L2`. (:

Comment: Can you try with adding the option `NSStringDrawingUsesDeviceMetrics`? It would look like `NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesDeviceMetrics`

Comment: It's also worth noting that `boundingRectWithSize` returns values in decimals. You may want to round those off before using them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution Found!

I just replaced the space with x in a temporary string to find the size of the textrect.

```
NSString *s = @"String with spacetext";
L1.text = s;
L2.text = @"2";

NSString *tempstring =[s stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"x"];
CGSize  textSize = { 150, 21 };
CGRect textRect = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",tempstring]
        boundingRectWithSize:textSize
        options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
        attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17]}
        context:nil];

L1.frame = CGRectMake(L1.frame.origin.x, L1.frame.origin.y, textRect.size.width, L1.frame.size.height);
L2.frame = CGRectMake(L1.frame.origin.x+textRect.size.width+10, L2.frame.origin.y, L2.frame.size.width, L2.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: "x" did not do the trick for me, but an "l" did it. Have not found a better solution, as your approach seem to be Font dependent. Anyway +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

Are these labels created in storyboard / XIB? Then you should perhaps switch off AutoLayout.

Also, `numberOfLines` as 0 means an infinite number of lines. This implies word wrapping which, however, is not shown due to the restricted height of your label. The word wrapping explains the phenomenon with the different lengths of string: if the **second** word is too long, it will break the line and show `...` to indicate that not all the text is shown.

Also, `adjustsFontSizeToWidth` will not always work, especially if the width of the label is not fixed, which is the case here.

Also, it is better to calculate the `textSize` based on the font rather than hardcoding it.

Also, the `stringWithFormat` to format a string as a string is redundant.

BTW, variable names should not be capitalized and human readable. So `label1`, while still not ideal, is preferable to `L1`.

Comment: Thnx for the reply, As you mentioned three things that minimumScaleFactor,adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth and numberOfLines will affect the result. I removed them, still the issue occurs. i'm using XIB for creating those labels. How to fix this issue?